# How to view (and bookmark) my questions covering all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, questions, network-profile

I was just trying to assemble a bookmark folder of listings of all my posts/questions in various forums.  I am able to get a nice link to everything except my Stack Exchange account.

I have bookmarks for listings of all my posts on: macscripter.net, discourse.nodered.org, oldhouseweb.com, reddit.com, discussions.apple.com, retropie.org.uk, etc..  There's a unique entry for all my posts and a few of them even show each post's current status (accepted answer or not), which makes it easy to quickly scan, when I have a slew of active questions to find where I posted what.

Why can I not find such a page for my overall stack exchange account?  Does it exist somewhere I've yet to locate?  The closest thing I've found is to bookmark my profile page.  I have to manually click the "posts" subcategory, because the bookmark directly to it does not render nicely:

https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/2347754?page=1&filter=posts

And bookmarking the page URL does not switch to the "posts" sub-tab automatically upon load:

https://stackexchange.com/users/2347754/username?tab=activity#posts

But in either case, this is not a unique list of posts showing their answered/unanswered status.  Those that are answered appear twice (as separate posts for asked & answered).  (You can click "accepts" and those are unique entries, but do not include the unanswered questions.)  Sometimes, the unanswered & answered entries are on different pages and it takes some clicking to find out if an asked question has been answered.  You can click on the question to find out, but when you have a lot of unanswered questions, that's a lot of clicking to just get an overview of what's left unanswered.

I understand that I can bookmark each stack site individually and get a unique listing and state of all my questions, but it would be more efficient if all questions from all sites could be viewed together.

It would be nice if there was a table with 1 row for each question that showed each question's status.  Plus, some extra stats would be nice too, like votes, views, etc..
And, please allow that page to be properly bookmarked.

Comment: Such a page might be nice.  In the meantime, the posts-tab thing is easily handled by a userscript.  A consolidated list (or even an RSS feed) is not too hard to code as a 1-page app that uses [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).